# Bootcamp Bluetooth mouse lagging when WiFi is enabled

Tags: wifi, bootcamp, bluetooth, mouse

The problem is very simple but the solution seems not so.
I'm trying to work with my Bluetooth mouse in Bootcamp, but when WiFi is enabled, the Bluetooth mouse is lagging.

I have read these and I applied all necessary changes:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8485451
- https://www.drivethelife.com/windows-10/fix-bluetooth-wireless-mouse-lag-windows-10.html

So `Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power` is unchecked for all `Network Adapters`, `Bluetooth Devices` and `Universal Serial Bus Controllers`.

I have updated the WiFi adapter driver through Apple Software Update to the latest version without any changes to my problem. After some restarts I moved to the previous version of the WiFi driver again to take back the option for `Bluetooth Collaboration`.

I can't figure out how to solve this problem. Any idea?

I have the MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **UPDATE #2 (27/0/2020)**

**Driver's Version 7.77.119.0 [21/4/2020], also works nicely with `Antenna Diversity` -> `Aux` and `Bluetooth Collaboration` -> `Auto`.**

---

UPDATE #1 (12/1/2020)

I can confirm that the newer version of the driver (7.77.110.0 [10/10/2019]) also works smoothly without any configuration.

---

After all, I found the solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/1291946/510975).

I disable the `Bluetooth Collaboration` option and I change the `Antena Diversity` property to AUX.

Instructutions:

1. From Device Mananager (Windox key + X)
2. Select Network Adapters
3. Double click your adapter (mine is Broadcom 802.11ac Network
   Adapter)
4. Click Advanced tab
5. For the property `Bluetooth Collaboration` select value `NO`
6. For the property `Antena Diversity` select value `AUX`

Instantly my bluetooth mouse worked smooth alongside my WiFi adapter.

---

If you don't see the two above properties you may need to downgrade your network's adapter driver.
As I saw those properties are available for:

- Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter Version 7.35.118.40[7/24/2015]
- Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter Version 7.35.118.73[7/12/2017]

But **NOT** in the latest version:

- Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter Version 7.35.118.83[4/20/2018]

More info [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8485451).